# Laravel 9 error "Vite manifest not found" on production server

Tags: laravel, deployment, vite, laravel-9, shared-hosting

I am deploying **Laravel 9** project to **shared hosting** (without the ability to **ssh** into the server so I can't **npm run build** in the server) and I am getting this error:

> **Vite manifest not found at: laravel_project/public/build/manifest.json**

I am using **FileZilla** to upload the project to the **CPanel**, I uploaded the **public** folder into **public_html** and configured the **index.php** file.

Before uploading the project i run **npm run build** locally on my **localhost** and everything works ok there.

Does anyone have a solution for this ?

I tried changing the **APP_ENV=production** but it didn't work.

Comment: Did you checked your build folder on your server?

Comment: @Dreamenemy in the server inside **public_html** folder i put what the **public** folder in laravel locally contains and it it contains the **build** folder

Comment: @Dreamenemy build your front-end assets on your local development machine, and then upload the built assets to your shared hosting server. Upload the entire public directory, including the public/build directory,

Comment: If your shared hosting has a folder called public_html then you mimic that folder locally, change index, etc. Of course build the assets locally, like Karl says. Make everything work locally and *then* upload it to your shared server

Comment: @KarlHill I did exactly that by running **npm run build** locally and then I uploaded what I got locally in my laravel **public** folder inside the **public_html** folder in the server including the **build** folder that contains **manifest.json** and the **assets** folder but I still getting the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I found a solution for that which is:

1. put all my **local** laravel files and folders including the **public** folder (of course after running **composer install** and **npm run build** locally) inside the **public_html** directory in the server
2. now inside the server in **public_html** directory move the two files **.htaccess** and **index.php** of the **public** folder one level up in way so that the **index.php** file and the **.htaccess** file are directly inside the **public_html** directory (this way you don't have to include **/public** in your **url** but instead access the application directly when you visit your website)
3. configure the content of **index.php** you just moved from **public** up to **public_html** in a way that its links point correctly to the content of the app inside **public_html**

for example:

`__DIR__.'/../storage/framework/maintenance.php'`

becomes

**`__DIR__.'/storage/framework/maintenance.php'`**

so that the /.. is removed

and the other links too like:

`__DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php'`

becomes

**`__DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php'`**

and

`__DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php'`

becomes

**`__DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php'`**

Answer (score 0):

I am having the exact same issue. What helped me is I not only added public contents to public_html but also additionally added the public folder to the production server with the same content. So it's duplicated files in public_html and public, but I think it's a better solution than adding the whole project into the public_html folder.
I would like to find a nicer solution for this issue though.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I solved my bug by creating a symbolic link between the "public_html" folder and the "public" folder with the following command, via SSH, on my server: "ln -s /path/to/folder/public_html /path/to/folder/public". This way, my two folders are always pointing to the same resources.